# How do I see if a character exists within each instance of the array as I type within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been struggling with this issue so I thought I'd come here to find the fix. I'm trying to filter my objects that are in an array to only show the ones that have for example "h" in them. 
This is how my array of objects is being constructed:

```
Object.keys(data.jello).forEach(function (id, SomeSearchValue) {
    var jello = data.jello[id];
    array.push({
        id: jello.id,
        name: jello.name,
        type: 'foo',
    });
}
```

For example, let's say my array consists of this for names.

```
array[blue, red, green, apple, abigail, alien]
```

So, I have an array of objects. In a search bar I type "a" and my array results are then all objects that have a letter 'a' in the name. so...

```
array[abigail, alien]
```

Then i type a "b" so my search is now "ab" and my array is ...

```
array[abigail]
```

So what would my code to implement this using jQuery? 
The part I'm stuck on most is the actual searching as the user types without using ajax.

I'm using jQuery. Ive tried things like `jQuery.grep()`, `inArray()` but cant seem to search includes. I've also tried `array.includes()`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you mean to tag with PHP?

Comment: Thought it might be useful as the array of objects is coming from a database through php logic

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#filter()`.

jQuery $.grep() is basically the same thing but also works on jQuery objects.

Following assumes you only want to search within `name` property and will accept the term found in any part of the name rather than just at beginning

```js
const data = [{name:'blue'}, {name:'red'}, {name:'green'}, {name:'apple'}, {name:'abigail'}, {name:'alien'}];

const term ='ab';

const filtered = data.filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))
// or use startsWith() to only match beginning of string

console.log(filtered)
```